# How to use variables exported from .scss file to create Material-UI theme?

Tags: reactjs, sass, material-ui, next.js

I'm trying to use some variables exported from global `.scss` file to create Material-UI theme. Problems occurs because those variables are `undefined` on server (I'm using `next.js` so pages are pre-rendered). How to make this work?

Error that I get (beacuse all colors are `undefined`):

```
Error: Material-UI: The color provided to augmentColor(color) is invalid.
The color object needs to have a `main` property or a `500` property.
```

Here are the important parts of my application.

_app.jsx

```
// General imports
import React from 'react';

// Components import
import App from 'next/app';
import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider, CssBaseline, StylesProvider, jssPreset } from '@material-ui/core';
import { create } from 'jss';

// Global styles and colors import
import '../styles/global.scss';
import colors from '../styles/colors.scss';

if (typeof document !== 'undefined') {
  const styleNode = document.createComment('jss-insertion-point');
  document.head.insertBefore(styleNode, document.head.firstChild);
}

/**
 * Material-UI theme.
 *
 * @type {Object}
 */
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: colors.primary,
      contrastText: colors.primaryText
    },
    secondary: {
      main: colors.secondary,
      contrastText: colors.secondaryText
    }
  }
});

class CustomApp extends App {
  /**
   * Handles the componentDidMount lifecycle event.
   *
   * @memberof MyApp
   */
  componentDidMount() {
    // Remove the server-side injected CSS.
    const jssStyles = document.querySelector('#jss-server-side');
    if (jssStyles) {
      jssStyles.parentElement.removeChild(jssStyles);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Renders the component.
   *
   * @returns component's elements
   * @memberof CustomApp
   */
  render() {
    const {
      Component,
      pageProps
    } = this.props;

    return (
     <>
        <StylesProvider
          jss={
            create({
              ...jssPreset(),
              // Define a custom insertion point that JSS will look for when injecting the styles into the DOM.
              insertionPoint: 'jss-insertion-point'
            })
          }
        >
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <CssBaseline />
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </ThemeProvider>
        </StylesProvider>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default CustomApp;
```

_document.jsx

```
// General imports
import React from 'react';

// Components import
import Document, { Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
import { ServerStyleSheets } from '@material-ui/core';

/**
 *
 *
 * @class CustomDocument
 * @extends {Document}
 */
class CustomDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <html lang="en">
        <Head>
          <meta charSet="utf-8" />
          <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </html>
    );
  }
}

CustomDocument.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  // Render app and page and get the context of the page with collected side effects.
  const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets();
  const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

  ctx.renderPage = () => originalRenderPage({
    enhanceApp: (App) => (props) => sheets.collect(<App isServer {...props} />)
  });

  const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);

  return {
    ...initialProps,
    // Styles fragment is rendered after the app and page rendering finish.
    styles: [...React.Children.toArray(initialProps.styles), sheets.getStyleElement()],
    isServer: false
  };
};

export default CustomDocument;
```

colors.scss

```
$color-primary: #2aa876;
$color-primary-text: #ffffff;
$color-secondary: #ffd265;
$color-secondary-text: #7e621d;

:export {
  primary: $color-primary;
  primaryText: $color-primary-text;
  secondary: $color-secondary;
  secondaryText: $color-secondary-text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Material UI uses a javascript based style solution (JSS) instead of a CSS pre-processor like SCSS ([see style solution](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/)).

This means it's not possible to customize the Material UI theme via SCSS variables. Nor is it possible to access the theme in your CSS/SCSS styles.

If you want to use SCSS for styling/theming, you might consider [Material Web Components instead](https://material.io/develop/web/).

Comment: Not sure if I understood you right. Anyways, if I would write `createMuiTheme(colors.primary  ? { ... } : { })` that would work, but user would se FOUC.

Comment: @radovix I think it's impossible to use SCSS with ```createMuiTheme```. Anyway, if you want to reuse classes or global colors in MUI, you can create an external style file, then import this file into the components that you want to use this style, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62374323/what-is-the-proper-way-of-using-the-styling-defined-inside-createmuitheme-alongs/62399418#62399418

Comment: I'm starting to believe that too. I managed to configure theme with colors from scss file, but with FOUC present. Anyway, thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

In **colors.scss** modify as below:

```
$theme-colors: (
    'primary': #2aa876,
    'primaryText': #ffffff,
    'secondary': #ffd265,
    'secondaryText': #7e621d,
);


@each $color, $value in $theme-colors {
  :export{
    $color: $value;
  }
}
```

import it as you're doing.

```
import colors from '../styles/colors.scss'; 
# colors.primary and other variable should work now.
```

Comment: `Syntax error: Selector ":export" is not pure (pure selectors must contain at least one local class or id)`

Comment: Updated answer. you can check again as i make change in export.

Comment: Error is not present any more, but this still doesn't solve my problem. Problem probably occurs due to pre-rendering when those colors are not yet available.